# C++ for loop terminated automatically safely for char * when index cross its length

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Consider the following for loop.

```
char temp[100];
char *str = "abab";
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; temp[i] = str[j];j++)
{
    if (str[j] == temp[i])
        i++;
    else
        i--;
}
```

It does not have terminating condition but still it manages to terminates after traversing "str".

Please explain.

Comment: @AlexandreCartaxo I think that's what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The loop does have a terminating condition, namely

```
temp[i] = str[j]
```

As the value of that is `str[j]`, the loop condition boils down to

```
for (j = 0; str[j]; j++)
```

This certainly traverses `str` exactly once since `str[j]` evaluates to `false` in this context if and only if `str[j] == '\0'`. `'\0'` is a special character that terminates all string literals and is used to terminate C style strings.

In the "real world", i.e. outside of toy programs, you should avoid "clever" code like this, even if it works.

Also note that the conversion from string literals to `char*` is deprecated and that every attempt to modify a string literal invokes undefined behavior. Use

```
const char *str = "abab";
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment expression `temp[i] = str[j]` has a value, which is the value that was assigned.

Since `str` is `\0` terminated (character value 0), when the loop reaches it and assigns it to `temp`, the expression evaluates to 0. And the loop condition becomes false.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is `temp[i] = str[j]`. That assigns and returns the assigned value. Therefore it will be evaluated to true for everything different to `\0` and false, when the terminating `\0` has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    char temp[100];
    const char *str = "abab";
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; temp[i] = str[j]; j++)
    {
        if (str[j] == temp[i])
            i++;
        else
            i--;
    }
    cout << (temp[4]  ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

Printing shows that the condition of the last iteration evaluates to false because it's zero ('\0' as end of string).

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of it, the loop run it course as its scan the whole word "abab" and the condition for the loop to end is str = temp, the final output of those variables are 4 = 4